# Capture archive html with BufferedReader toString , response print "\"

Tags: java, json, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I have to extract the contents of an html file that is in the resources folder of my project in spring boot.

The point is that I already read the file but when passing it as a response of the console service it paints me perfectly, but in the service response the whole string is with "\" "in each double quotation mark found in the file.

This is my method:

```
private String convertHTML() {
    Resource resource = loader.getResource("classpath:static/email.html");
    String result = "";
    try {
        String title = "Hi, I'm a title";
        String body = "Hi, I'm the body of the message :)";
        InputStream ip = resource.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(ip);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          String str;
          while((str = reader.readLine())!= null){
              sb.append(str.trim());
          }
         result = sb.toString().replaceAll("%s", title).replaceAll("%0s", body);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

**In console print ok without "\":**

[image]

**In Response of service via Postman:**

[image]

**All response returns it to me with "\".**

How do I do that when I return the string that does not happen to me?

Or do you have a better option to perform this process?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please check "Raw" body in postman. You can also try to use "Send and Download" option of postman and save output directly to local file and check.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the output of Postman.
I assume you're using JSON around your String?
The escaping of the characters comes from your JSON encoding (?) around the String because '"' characters need to be escaped to not be intermixed with JSON string delimiters:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "\"hello world\""
}
```

The escaping will be invisible in the decoded JSON payload, don't worry.